# How to change the ReadOnly attribute in realtime for use with PropertyGrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, attributes, real-time, propertygrid

I got a properties class that I send to a *PropertyGrid*.  I want to change the `[readonly]` *attribute* of some properties in realtime.  Below is an example of such a property in vb.net...

```
<CategoryAttribute("Graph Limits"), _
      Browsable(True), _
      [ReadOnly](False), _
      BindableAttribute(False), _
      DefaultValueAttribute(100), _
      DesignOnly(False), _
      DescriptionAttribute("Maximum value")> _
Public Property Max() As Double
    Get
        Return _Max
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Double)
        _Max = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta-data is static as far as I know, so it cannot be changed at runtime.
I'd suggest you create a wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using a method similar to the following in you class:

```
Private Sub SetReadOnlyProperty(ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal [readOnly] As Boolean)
    Dim descriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties([GetType]())(propertyName)
    Dim attribute As ReadOnlyAttribute = DirectCast(descriptor.Attributes(GetType(ReadOnlyAttribute)), ReadOnlyAttribute)
    Dim fieldToChange As FieldInfo = attribute.[GetType]().GetField("isReadOnly", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    fieldToChange.SetValue(attribute, [readOnly])
End Sub
```

Note: You need to Set the `<[ReadOnly]()>` or `<ReadOnlyAttribute()>` of every Property in your class to some default value for this to work.